# How to load UIWebView images, when it's scrolled to these image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiwebview

In `UITableView` we can easily load images, from URLs or databases, on rows only then, if users has scrolled to this rows.

When I load in my `UIWebView` very big webpages with lots of image, it sometimes freezes scrolling. I'm searching for similar method to load images as for `UITableView`. I already using `NSURLCache`. I just want to make my browser faster.

Thanks for advise!!

Comment: each cell need UIWebview to show image or not ?

Comment: No, I need improve UIWebView perfomance, and mobile safari make it faster loading UIWebView content icluded images only then, if user has scrolled to these images.

Comment: your problem is load image (with image Url) to tableview ?

Comment: NO, that i already make like LazyLoadTable app example.

Comment: did you try SDWebImage or AFNetworking Lib. It support lazyLoading and cache Iamge for you. I think it better than add webview to load Image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next to implementing some sort of caching yourself (which only will help if the images in question were already loaded once before, of course - that's what caching is about) you don't have that much influence on how an `UIWebView` is displaying a web page. If the page is under your control you can do some server side optimisation of the page so it loads faster in your app, but otherwise you're out of luck.

For some intelligent caching in your app look at `NSURLProtocol` (and a nice explanation here: http://robnapier.net/offline-uiwebview-nsurlprotocol).